# coordinating filesystem activity in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best practice for coordinating access to files in node.js?

I'm trying to write an http based file uploader for very large files (10sGB) that is resumable.  I'm trying to figure out what the best approach is to handle two people trying to upload the same file at the same time...  I'm also trying to think ahead to the possibility where more than one copy of the node.js http server is running behind a load balancer, which means catching duplicate uploads can't rely on just the code itself.

In python, for example, you can create a file by passing the correct flags to the open() call to force an atomic create.  Not sure if the default node.js open new file is atomic.

Another option I thought of, but don't really want to pursue, is using a database with an async driver that supports atomic transactions to track this state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on HackerNews under a response to someone complaining about some of the same things in node.js.  I'll put it here for completeness.  This allows me to at least lock some file writes in node.js like I wanted to.

> IsaacSchlueter 4 hours ago | link
>
> You can open a file with O_EXCL if you pass in the open flags as a
>   number. (You can find them on require("constants"), and they need to
>   be binary-OR'ed together.) This isn't documented. It should be. It
>   should probably also be exposed in a cleaner way. Most of the rest of
>   what you describe is APIs that need to be polished and refined a bit.
>   The boundaries are well defined at this point, though. We probably
>   won't add another builtin module at this point, or dramatically expand
>   what any of them can do. (I don't consider seek() dramatic, it's just
>   tricky to get right given JavaScript's annoying Number problems.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to know if multiple users are uploading the same file, you will have to identify the files somehow. Hashing is best for this. First, hash the entire file on the client side to identify it. Tell the server the hash of the file, if there is already a file on the server with the same hash, then the file has already been uploaded or is currently being uploaded.

Since this is an http file server, you will likely want users to upload files from a browser. You can get the contents of a file with a browser using the [File Reader API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader). Unfortunately as of now [this isn't widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader). You might have to use something like flash to to get it to work in other browsers.

As you stream the file into memory with the file reader, you will want to break it into chunks and hash the chunks. Then send the server all of the file's hashed chunks. It's important that you break the file into chunks and hash those individual chunks instead of the contents of the entire file because otherwise the client could send one hash and upload an entire different file.

After the hashes are received and compared to other files' hashes and it turns out someone else is currently uploading the same file, the server then decides which user gets to upload which chunks of the file. The server then tells the uploading clients what chunks it wants from them, and the clients upload their corresponding chunks.

As each chunk is finished uploading, it is rehashed on the server and compared with the original array of hashes to verify that the user is uploading the correct file.

Comment: I should clarify that I've implemented almost exactly as you describe, except I'm asking for clarification on the part where, I'll quote you, "...if it turns out someone else is currently uploading the same file, the server then decides which user gets to upload which chunks".  How do I implement this in node.js (details)?  How does the server distinguish if a chunk has been abandoned by its current uploader?  If two chunks get uploaded at the same time how do I guarantee one is accepted and the other denied (some sort of atomic operation)?

Comment: Pick a chunk size like say 1MB and distribute the chunks between the users uploading. Typically the first user will get to upload the first chunks and the second gets to upload the second half of the file. When the n user starts to upload the same file, take 1/n of the remaining chunks from the current uploaders and give them to the new user. If you kept a record of the initial array of hashes each client has to send, you can set a flag on each chunk when they're finished uploading and been verified.

Comment: And under this system, users will have to send a file's hash before they start uploading. They should never be in a situation where two users are uploading the same chunk from the same file.